# Read sensor data with ROS

Tags: gazebo-sensor, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've just started to learn ROS and Gazebo and now, finally, I can connect ROS with Gazebo (I control a robot in Gazebo with keyboard using turtlesim turtle_teleop_key.

Now I want to add some sensors to my robot and read the data from ROS. How can I do it? Do I need to code a Gazebo plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20429/read-sensor-data-with-ros/) by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> Now I want to add some sensors to my robot and read the data from ROS. How can I do it? Do I need to code a Gazebo plugin?

To extract data from Gazebo, you have three options:

1. Use a [pre-existing Gazebo Plugin/Sensor that publishes the data to ROS](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs)
2. Use a pre-existing [Gazebo Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/plugins/) or [Sensor](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/gazebo/sensors/) that publishes the data to the Gazebo Transport Layer. You'll have to access this data (e.g. from a ROS Node) via the [Gazebo Transport Library](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=transport).
3. Write your own [custom Gazebo Plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i1#Intro) that publishes sensor data using either of the above methods.

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) with karma: 609 on 2018-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1